# Can Blazor kill a browser window without using JavaScript?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Blazor can only close a window with JavaScript if there's no window history, because JavaScript doesn't open windows when you're clicking on links to get to a particular page, and because of security precautions.

But is that the only way Blazor can close a browser window? With JavaScript?

Comment: I don't think there is. I haven't seen a way to do that without JS. But it's a good question.